# PHP Include Not Working on One Page

Tags: php, .htaccess

So, I finally got the PHP include function to work by tweaking the .htaccess file yesterday. [The index shows up perfectly](http://sculptcoach.com/). But get this, I duplicate the index.html file, rename it and [upload it as another page](http://sculptcoach.com/personal-training-london.html) (as a template to work from) and now the PHP include function is not working on that page, even though it's exactly the same code hosted on the same server with the same .htaccess file.

The original file is also .html and the server is set up to interpret it properly, and does work in this way with [another website](http://yogadetoxretreat.co.uk) which is on the same server.

.htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-page.html
#
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png)$">
ErrorDocument 404 /404.gif
</FilesMatch>

Options +MultiViews
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: The second file is an Html file.  Your server is not setup to interpret the file as a PHP file I'm assuming.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the .htaccess file please?

Comment: @yzmir Both files are HTML files and the server is set up to interpret html files.

Comment: @Homer6 Sure, I have posted it above. Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "PHP include function is not working on that page"? Are you getting an error message? What is the specific symptom? What is your expectation?

Comment: @Homer6 Sure, if you follow the link, you'll see that the parts of the page which should be called by the PHP are not showing at all. That page should look exactly the same as the .index page because it's a duplicate of it.

Comment: It would be useful if you pasted in some code to show us what you're doing.

Comment: Well...what's in your `.html` file (not all of the markup mind you, just the essence) and a snippet from your PHP file. Have you tried reducing this down to a simple reproducible example?

Comment: I've got it working now, thanks guys! It turned out that I'd duplicated an outdated copy of the index file. Sorry, feel free to take your anger out on me with the down-vote button ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add this to your .htaccess?

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

My guess is that your .htaccess doesn't work and apache's configuration is handling it, but only for index files.

Comment: Can you put some PHP code in your secondary page to prove that PHP is not being parsed?